# wpf datagrid.itemsource filter

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid in wpf and I used the markup ItemSource="{Binding CompanyTable}" in it. but the problem is, the datagrid loads every single record from the CompanyTable. i'd like to filter it and prevent every entry with a StatusId=0 to show in the datagrid, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `RowFilter` and then add rows to a new datatable, may be it looks like :

```
        DataTable newdt = new DataTable();
        DataRow[] dr = CompanyTable.Select("StatusId = 0");
        foreach (DataRow row in dr)
        {
            newdt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: where will I put the rowfilter? i tried typing it but it turned red

Comment: put it before you set datagrid's itemsource and binding newdt to datagrid.